# JSON query with no element name

Tags: json, mongodb

How to extract data from json document where element name is still changing. This json fragment is dump from mongo with data from FlightRadar API.
I wish to only get the elements ad5913d and ad55d85.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("57c47c86ef20310d0ebdd2af"),
    "full_count" : 12643,
    "version" : 4,
    "ad5913d" : [
        "800B67",
        37.7181,
        47.4987,
        143,
        45000,
        459,
        "3665",
        "F-UBBL1",
        "",
        "",
        1472494567,
        "TZX",
        "",
        "",
        0,
        -64,
        "VTJUI",
        0
    ],
    "ad55d85" : [
        "",
        37.9425,
        43.5465,
        104,
        45000,
        504,
        "5532",
        "F-UBBN1",
        "GLEX",
        "",
        1472494551,
        "",
        "",
        "",
        0,
        -64,
        "GLEX",
        0
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the other fields are always the same you could use 
db.collectionName.find( {}, {"_id" : 0,
    "full_count" : 0,
    "version":0})